# ReactJS - how to auto refresh after submitting form

Tags: html, reactjs

When i submit the page never stops loading and i have to manually refresh the page to get the input in my table. the table.js and submit.js is in two different components. So how do i make my page automatically refresh alternativly if i could add som eventlistner in the table component to get the API again after a submit.

class Submit extends Component {

```
render() {
    return (
        <>
            <form action='http://localhost:3001/api/post' method="POST" onsubmit="return false">
                <input type="input" class="text" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" required />
                <input type="input" class="text" placeholder="Model" required />
                <input type="input" class="text" name="price" placeholder="Price" required />
                <button type="submit" class='button'>Submit</button> 
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

}

function Table() {

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get/carmodels").then((response) => { 
      setCarModelList(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  const [carModelList, setCarModelList] = useState([])

  const DeleteCar = (val) => { 
    const next = [...carModelList];
    const removedItems = next.splice(next.indexOf(val), 1);
   const deleteCarModel = Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/api/delete/${val.id}`); 

   setCarModelList(next);
    return deleteCarModel

  }  

  const renderTableData = () => {
    return carModelList.map((val) => (
        <tr class>
           <td>{val.id}</td>
            <td>{val.brand}</td>
            <td>{val.model}</td>
            <td>{val.price}</td>
            <td>
                <button id="delete" onClick={() => DeleteCar(val)}>Delete</button> 
            </td>
        </tr>))
  }

return (
    <table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {renderTableData()}
      </tbody>
      </table>
    );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ39v.png)Add UseState for another alert variable that is initialized to false, when you click the submit button, you make it true, and after you fetch, you turn it back to false. example in the image attached

```
const [alert, setAlert] = useState(true);

const handleSubmit= (e)=> {

setAlert(true)

useEffect(()=>{
// perform your fetch
 setAlert(false)
},[alert])
 
}
```

Comment: Please include code in a codeblock in the post, not as an image